# How to summarize score variable along time into a single variable?

Tags: feature-selection, descriptive-statistics

I have a set of clients, and for each client I have a score (let's say between 1 and 6, where 1 is the best and 6 is the worst possible) given per month. For example:

01.2016: 2.25

02.2016: 1.88

...

06.2018: 3.35

07.2018: 3.06

My question is the following: how could I somehow summarize the behaviour of this variable during the given period into a single value?

This value should also if possible reflect the fluctuations of the score during the studied period, such that clients with a stable score can be distinguished from clients that fluctuate a lot.

I thought about something like: score1-score2/score1 and then go summing the values up, but I am not sure this is the best approach and I would like to know more options.

Comment: First plot the data to see what type of relationship there may be: linear, u-shape, etc.

Comment: Thanks @JoelW. There is no clear linear/polinomial correlation between the variable and the date. The behaviour of this score variable strongly depends on other variables that contribute to the stability of the company. It is a very fluctuating value.

Comment: What is your research hypothesis?  What do you hope to detect or describe?  If you are interested in stability over time, you might just compute the variance of the observations for each client, separately.  You could average these to get an overall figure that describes the average level of stability.